# CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) in Visualforce Pages on Public Force.com Sites

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, platform-bug, csrf

**Background**

On one of our public Salesforce Sites (Force.com Site) we allow users to create or/and update contacts "within" salesforce. To do so I'm using `<apex:form>`. In case Javascript is enabled the data is send via ajax to salesforce (custom endpoint); In case Javascript is disabled the standard "POST" request will send the data to salesforce.

**Observations**

1. It looks like CSRF protection is not available for Salesforce Sites. (The hidden input field is missing)
2. There is no CSRF protection for "public" Sites.

***Questions***

1. How to enable CSRF protection on public Salesforce / Force.com Sites?
2. Is there an alternative way to implement CSRF protection?

**Screenshots**

As a "Salesforce Standard User" there is CSRF protection:

[image: CSRF protection]

On public sites CSRF protection is missing

[image: CSRF protection is missing]

Comment: are both vf pages exactly the same? Just double checking because if you define an action attribute in the apex:page the csrf is lost..

Comment: It's the same page.

Comment: Great Question & very good observation!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can implement CSRF protection for your public site:

You will need to define NewGuid() function which will generate GUID:
Here is one example how you can implement GuidUtil.NewGuid().

```
Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
String guid = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);
system.debug(guid);
```

In your controller create a variable CSRF_ID and in constructor set the value for this variable:

```
CSRF_ID = GuidUtil.NewGuid();
```

Once GuidUtil.NewGuid() is set use it in controller action method check the value of CSRF_ID and if its matching then the request is legitimate otherwise not.

Hope that it helps.